# How to set boolean true in php curl

Tags: php

How to set *fixed_rate* boolean true in this php curl

> fixed_rate(optional) - boolean, can be true or false. Returns avaliable currencies with minimum and maximum amount of the exchange.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.nowpayments.io/v1/currencies',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'x-api-key: <your_api_key>'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Set it where? As a querystring parameter? Request body parameter? JSON property? XML node? Or what? You've quoted a snippet of documentation, but it's completely out of context. Your request is unclear and we also don't know how/why/where you're stuck with implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.nowpayments.io/v1/currencies?fixed_rate=true',
```

You should just set fixed-rate as a parameter to url.

Comment: I already did it before but Not working

Comment: what is your response?